# Create reveal footer in full-page.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullpage.js

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="fullpage">
      <section class="vertical-scrolling" id="section1">
      
      </section>
      
       <section class="vertical-scrolling" id="section2">
      
      </section>
       <section class="vertical-scrolling" id="section3">
      
      </section>
       <section class="vertical-scrolling" id="section4">
      
      </section>
       <section class="vertical-scrolling" id="section5">
      
      </section>
      
      
      <footer>t
        my footer content goes here
      </footer>
 </div>
```

Hello I am using full-page.js template. I want to implement footer into that but when I take footer into my `<section>` it creates a full page but my footer size is not full page. I want to make my footer to reveal when I scroll down to the last section. I havent added cdn of fullpage.js

Answer (score 0):

```
make footer position as absolute and bottom as 0px.
```

try this  [jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Rubhan/zsa0c14k/)